# How to reduce code repetition on AWS Deequ

Tags: scala, aws-glue

I have some 5 datasets (which will grow in future so generalizing is important) that call the same code base with common headings but I am not sure how to go about ensuring that

1. loads datasets
2. Call the code and write to different folders.
   If you can help that would be awesome since I am new in Scala. Theses are Jobs on AWS Glue. The only thing which changes is the input file and the location of the results.

Here's some three samples for example - I want to reduce repetition of the code:

```
import com.amazon.deequ.{VerificationSuite, VerificationResult}
import com.amazon.deequ.VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame
import com.amazon.deequ.checks.{Check, CheckLevel}
import com.amazon.deequ.constraints.{ConstrainableDataTypes}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{length, max}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession




object Deequ {






def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("dq")
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("dq").getOrCreate()

 val dataset = spark.read.option("header",true).option("delimiter",",").csv("s3://ct-ire- 
 fin-stg-data-dev-raw-gib/templates 
 /Contract_Portfolio_Assignment/Contract_Portfolio_Assignement_Compass/contract-portfolio- 
 assignment-compass - Sheet1.csv") 


 val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
 // data to run the verification on
 .onData(dataset)
 // define a data quality check
  .addCheck(
  Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Template Validations") 



  .hasDataType("* Contract Category", ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Contract Category", _==1)
  .isComplete("* Contract Category")


  .hasDataType("* Contract ID",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
   .hasMaxLength("* Contract ID", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("* Contract ID")
  
  
  .hasDataType("* Key Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Key Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Key Date")
  
  
  .hasDataType("* Portfolio Category",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Portfolio Category", _ <= 4)
  .isComplete("* Portfolio Category")

  
  .hasDataType("* Tranche Start Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Tranche Start Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Tranche Start Date")
 // .isContainedIn("Portfolio Category", Array("2100"))

  
  
  .hasDataType("Portfolio",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Portfolio", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("Portfolio")
  
  
  
  
  .hasDataType("Source System",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
  .hasMaxLength("Source System", _ <= 10)
  .isComplete("Source System")
  .isContainedIn("Source System", Array("LFST", "CLPB","CLCB","CLHR","CCLU"))

  
  .hasDataType("Delivery Package",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Delivery Package", _ <= 20)
  .isComplete("Delivery Package")
 // .isContainedIn("Legal Entity", Array("LP01", "LLAL"))
 

 )
  


  // compute metrics and verify check conditions
  .run()
    }
    //val metrics1 = successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult1)
    val resultDataFrame = checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, verificationResult)
    resultDataFrame.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://ct-ire-fin-stg-data-dev-raw- 
    gib/template_validations/Contract-Portfolio-Assignment-Validations/Contract-Portfolio- 
    Assignment-Compass/")
     }}
```

Here's the second code base:

```
import com.amazon.deequ.{VerificationSuite, VerificationResult}
import com.amazon.deequ.VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame
import com.amazon.deequ.checks.{Check, CheckLevel}
import com.amazon.deequ.constraints.{ConstrainableDataTypes}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{length, max}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession




object Deequ {






 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("dq")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("dq").getOrCreate()

  val dataset = spark.read.option("header",true).option("delimiter",",").csv("s3://ct-ire- 
  fin-stg-data-dev-raw-gib/templates /Contract_Portfolio_Assignment/Contract-Portfolio- 
  Assignment-GIP/Portfolio-Assignment-GIP - Sheet1.csv") 


  val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
  // data to run the verification on
 .onData(dataset)
 // define a data quality check
 .addCheck(
   Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Template Validations") 



  .hasDataType("* Contract Category", ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Contract Category", _==1)
  .isComplete("* Contract Category")


  .hasDataType("* Contract ID",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
   .hasMaxLength("* Contract ID", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("* Contract ID")
  
  
  .hasDataType("* Key Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Key Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Key Date")
  
  
  .hasDataType("* Portfolio Category",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Portfolio Category", _ <= 4)
  .isComplete("* Portfolio Category")

  
  .hasDataType("* Tranche Start Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Tranche Start Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Tranche Start Date")
 // .isContainedIn("Portfolio Category", Array("2100"))

  
  
  .hasDataType("Portfolio",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Portfolio", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("Portfolio")
  
  
  
  
  .hasDataType("Source System",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
  .hasMaxLength("Source System", _ <= 10)
  .isComplete("Source System")
  .isContainedIn("Source System", Array("LFST", "CLPB","CLCB","CLHR","CCLU"))

  
  .hasDataType("Delivery Package",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Delivery Package", _ <= 20)
  .isComplete("Delivery Package")
 // .isContainedIn("Legal Entity", Array("LP01", "LLAL"))
 

  )
  


   // compute metrics and verify check conditions
   .run()
     }
  //val metrics1 = successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult1)
  val resultDataFrame = checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, verificationResult)
   resultDataFrame.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://ct-ire-fin-stg-data-dev-raw- 
    gib/template_validations/Contract-Portfolio-Assignment-Validations/Contract-Portfolio- 
     Assignement-GIP-Validations/")
      }}
```

Here's the third one:

```
import com.amazon.deequ.{VerificationSuite, VerificationResult}
import com.amazon.deequ.VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame
import com.amazon.deequ.checks.{Check, CheckLevel}
import com.amazon.deequ.constraints.{ConstrainableDataTypes}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{length, max}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession




 object Deequ {






    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("dq")
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("dq").getOrCreate()

      val dataset = spark.read.option("header",true).option("delimiter",",").csv("s3://ct- 
      ire-fin-stg-data-dev-raw-gib/templates /Contract_Portfolio_Assignment/Portfolio- 
      Assignment-Mobilife/Mobilife-Portforlio-Assessment - Sheet1.csv") 


      val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
       // data to run the verification on
    .onData(dataset)
    // define a data quality check
    .addCheck(
       Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Template Validations") 



  .hasDataType("* Contract Category", ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Contract Category", _==1)
  .isComplete("* Contract Category")


  .hasDataType("* Contract ID",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
   .hasMaxLength("* Contract ID", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("* Contract ID")
  
  
  .hasDataType("* Key Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Key Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Key Date")
  
  
  .hasDataType("* Portfolio Category",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Portfolio Category", _ <= 4)
  .isComplete("* Portfolio Category")

  
  .hasDataType("* Tranche Start Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Tranche Start Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Tranche Start Date")
 // .isContainedIn("Portfolio Category", Array("2100"))

  
  
  .hasDataType("Portfolio",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Portfolio", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("Portfolio")
  
  
  
  
  .hasDataType("Source System",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
  .hasMaxLength("Source System", _ <= 10)
  .isComplete("Source System")
  .isContainedIn("Source System", Array("LFST", "CLPB","CLCB","CLHR","CCLU"))

  
  .hasDataType("Delivery Package",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Delivery Package", _ <= 20)
  .isComplete("Delivery Package")
   // .isContainedIn("Legal Entity", Array("LP01", "LLAL"))
 

    )
  


     // compute metrics and verify check conditions
    .run()
      }
   //val metrics1 = successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult1)
    val resultDataFrame = checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, verificationResult)
    resultDataFrame.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://ct-ire-fin-stg-data-dev-raw- 
    gib/template_validations/Contract-Portfolio-Assignment-Validations/contract-portfolio- 
     assessment_Mobilife-Validations/")
      }}
```

Comment: you could just create a function and put all your common code in the function and call it from different places.

Comment: I get this. I am just not sure what return type does Deequ return and how to pass datasets to functions in scala. But I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question, you could create the function that does the common logic and you could call the same function from different places. You could have multiple parameters for your function based on different values that you have for your different work flows.

```
//Common Function just for your reference but you can modify it as you want.
object CommonHelper {
  def ProcessDataSet(spark : SparkSession,sourcePath : String , targetPath : String) : Unit = {
    
    val dataset = spark.read.option("header",true).option("delimiter",",").csv(sourcePath) 
  val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
  // data to run the verification on
 .onData(dataset)
 // define a data quality check
 .addCheck(
   Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Template Validations") 

  .hasDataType("* Contract Category", ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Contract Category", _==1)
  .isComplete("* Contract Category")

  .hasDataType("* Contract ID",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
   .hasMaxLength("* Contract ID", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("* Contract ID")
  
  .hasDataType("* Key Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Key Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Key Date")
  
  .hasDataType("* Portfolio Category",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral )
  .hasMaxLength("* Portfolio Category", _ <= 4)
  .isComplete("* Portfolio Category")

  .hasDataType("* Tranche Start Date",ConstrainableDataTypes.Integral)
  .hasMaxLength("* Tranche Start Date", _ <= 8)
  .isComplete("* Tranche Start Date")
 // .isContainedIn("Portfolio Category", Array("2100"))

  .hasDataType("Portfolio",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Portfolio", _ <= 40)
  .isComplete("Portfolio")
  
  .hasDataType("Source System",ConstrainableDataTypes.String )
  .hasMaxLength("Source System", _ <= 10)
  .isComplete("Source System")
  .isContainedIn("Source System", Array("LFST", "CLPB","CLCB","CLHR","CCLU"))

  .hasDataType("Delivery Package",ConstrainableDataTypes.String)
  .hasMaxLength("Delivery Package", _ <= 20)
  .isComplete("Delivery Package")
 // .isContainedIn("Legal Entity", Array("LP01", "LLAL"))
  )
   // compute metrics and verify check conditions
   .run()
     }
  //val metrics1 = successMetricsAsDataFrame(spark, analysisResult1)
  val resultDataFrame = checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, verificationResult)
   resultDataFrame.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(targetPath)
  }
}
```

Now you can call that from the main function in the start up object as below. I have shown it for one dataset you can reuse it for others.

```
object Deequ {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("dq")
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("dq").getOrCreate()
val sourcePath1 = "s3://ct-ire-fin-stg-data-dev-raw-gib/templates/Contract_Portfolio_Assignment/Contract-Portfolio-Assignment-GIP/Portfolio-Assignment-GIP - Sheet1.csv"
   val targetPath1 = "s3://ct-ire-fin-stg-data-dev-raw-gib/template_validations/Contract-Portfolio-Assignment-Validations/Contract-Portfolio-Assignement-GIP-Validations/"
  CommonHelper.ProcessDataSet(spark,sourcePath1,targetPath1) //you can call this function from multiple places based on how you want to use that.
      }}
```

Comment: This is weird, I get this error: SourcePathGIP is not a member of String





Compilation result: /tmp/g-45f32e4bd89eb6c2fbf8df971fdf9930d7cdfd60-2885378844415257246/script_2021-02-24-07-15-10.scala:75: error: value sourcePathGIP is not a member of object String String sourcePathGIP = "s3://ct-ire- fin-stg-data-dev-raw-gib/templates /Contract_Portfolio_Assignment/Contract-Portfolio- Assignment-GIP/Portfolio-Assignment-GIP - Sheet1.csv"

Comment: Any ideas why would this be? Cause I can see I am passing Strings. I am working on AWS Glue.

Comment: use val instead of String and try.. I have updated the answer

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work (using val) and it didn't work. But your structure makes sense to me I don't know why it's failing.

Comment: Make sure you have the whole s3 path inside double quotes in the same line as in the answer. I think it should work. Don't let the value to be on multiple lines.

Comment: I had to copy the path again from s3 instead of using the one here... encording issue or something. But works now. Many thanks.

Comment: you can upvote and accept the answer if it works